# always routed to signin page

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm trying to check if a user is signed in. The users are signed in via google sign in. If a user is signed in, then I want the app to show the description page, else it should show the sign in page. Here is my code for that:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Future<FirebaseUser> getCurrentUser() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((value) {
      if(value != null)
        UserSingleton().fireUser = value;
      return value;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: getCurrentUser() == null ? SignInPage() : DescriptionPage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/SignInPage': (BuildContext context) => SignInPage(),
        '/DescriptionPage': (BuildContext context) => DescriptionPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

What I want is when people open the app, they should be directed to description page if they haven't signed out before closing the app. If they have signed out, I want them to be directed to sign in page. 
When I run the app, I'm routed to the signin page regardless of whether a user is signed in or not.

How do I fix this?

Comment: i think your getCurrentUser method should be async. right now your method is not async and because of that you can not get data which result into null value, so it is transferring to SignInPage.

Comment: You should to use Statefulwidget rather than stateless widget. How you can listen changed state of your object. 
Use StatefulWidgets and call your function in initState(){} method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use  onAuthStateChanged,

> The recommended way to get the current user is by setting an observer on the Auth object

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users?authuser=0#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  onAuthStateChanged() {
    FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    return new StreamBuilder(
        stream: _auth.onAuthStateChanged,
        builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return DescriptionPage();
          }
          return SignInPage();
        })
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: onAuthStateChanged(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/SignInPage': (BuildContext context) => SignInPage(),
        '/DescriptionPage': (BuildContext context) => DescriptionPage(),
      },
    );
  }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You always go to the signin page, because `getCurrentUser()` is asynchronous, as you can see you are calling `then()` method on it which means it returns a `Future<AuthResult>` :

https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Therefore when doing `getCurrentUser() == null`, its always going to be null because the `Future` still didn't finish retrieving the value. To solve this, you need to use `Stateful` widget instead of stateless, and then inside your `State` class override the method `initState`:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((res) {
      print(res);
      if (res != null) {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DescriptionPage(),
        );
      }
      else
      {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignInPage()),
        );
      }
    });
  }
```

`then()` will contain a callback which will be called when the future completes, and then you can navigate to the correct page.

Comment: I tried this, but I didn't get the expected result. I was still routed to the signin page, regardless of whether the user was signed in or not. It's okay though, Erika's answer worked.